# How to make instances, points appear only inside the empty cube volume?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this long plane full of points that I'll turn into cars on a road.

[image]

But I want a cube/empty cube to act as a mask and the cars should appear in from an invisible boundary of that cube empty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this in minute 3:08 https://youtu.be/tolqBEyiSs0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a raycast on the cube from the distributed points.

When the raycast is pointing down, and a face of the cube is hit, you can use that as a selection when instantiating:

[image]

---

**Update**

However, in your concrete case you are using different scaling of the objects, so you would have to either apply the scaling of the objects (*Apply > Scale*), or include the cube when using it with `Object Info` with the setting *Relative*.

Also note the settings in the *Object Properties*. Here I created a cube and set *Display As* to the value *Wire* so that it does not interfere in the *3D Viewport*.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but this doesn't seem to do much in my case, actually not getting this result at all. the instances are still out of the the cube geometry. Also note that I don't want the cube boundary to show. I want to make it appear that instances are being revealed from a invisible boundary

Comment: @samar In principle, the technique I show here in the example works, but I'll be happy to take a closer look with your file. Please be so kind and share your file with us: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have uploaded the file. the link should be up on the question post

Comment: @samar All right, I have changed the answer accordingly. Now it should work for you.

Comment: this was very helpful. thank you. I have the object in the mesh bounds now. But you see I was hoping to use that Set Position to move and animate the cars (instances) appearing in an and heading out (appearing and disappearing) from the cube invisible edges

Comment: Ok that is sorted too. Just animating from viewport works. Thanks a lot @quellenform

Comment: @samar You're welcome!